# Has anyone been able to take TFS Team Web Access and successfully expose it to clients?

Tags: tfs, clearquest

We have recently switched from the Rational stack (ClearQuest/ClearCase etc..) over to TFS 2008 for our .NET group and one of the challenges that we are seeing are some of the limitations of the Team System Web Access as far as what work items a client can view.  Has anyone been able to take TSWA and successfully expose it to clients while controlling what kind of work items they are able to view?

Answer (score 2):

What was formerly called Team System [Work Item Web Access](http://blogs.msdn.com/hakane/archive/2008/04/09/what-is-work-item-web-access-wiwa.aspx) (WIWA) is your answer and is now called "[Work Item Only View](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=3ECD00BA-972B-4120-A8D5-3D38311893DE&displaylang=en)" . It's an extension to Team System Web Access (TSWA).

Download and install the [Visual Studio Team System Web Access 2008 SP 1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=3ECD00BA-972B-4120-A8D5-3D38311893DE&displaylang=en) pack, you will get both TSWA and WIWA - they will be available at different urls - The final window of the install will give you those URLs.

If you've already installed it I beieve the "Wrk Item Only View" is in a "WIWA" subdirectory of the root TSWA url.

Comment: Problem with WIWA is that the client can only view bugs that they have submitted so they wouldn't be able to see any internal bugs or tasks.  We have looked at this option already and it's more like a bug submission portal then an external view into TFS work items.

Comment: HI think you are facing restrictions of the TFS licensing model. Right now WIWA is as open as it gets for "supported apps" that don't violate the licensing model. Sorry, even if you find a way to take TSWA and expose to un-licensed clients it would be a pretty obvious violation.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about customers being able to view and create only their own work items on a per-customer basis, or something more like a public vs. private scenario?

If it is the latter, you could create a Team Project with the sole intent of acting as a triage center for issues that customers report and create.  Although, I will admit that is not the cleanest solution.  The only reason that I bring that option up is that we are considering a similar approach for our customer service department to use.

I would be interested in seeing other options from more seasoned TFS users.  We are new to party, too, and know that we have only barely scratched the surface in what we can do with it.

Comment: If you just want customers to be able to submit new work items and only view their own submitted work items I believe that the TFS Work Item Web Access site does precisely that.  But yes as you mentioned we aer looking more for a client public/private work item scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Depending upon the restrictions you might be able to use the 'work item only view' which according to Microsoft:

"Team System Web Access provides a work item only view that restricts functionality so that you can create and view only your own work items."

More info at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668124.aspx

http://visualstudiomagazine.com/columns/article.aspx?editorialsid=2832

Answer (score 1):

just for reference, i've recently come up against this, and the security convolusion that IS tfs.

i worked out how to do this easily, and wrote up a blog post to make it clearer for others. I am using TFS 2010, but most of the same applies to 2008.

the post is at:

http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2010/07/14/quick-and-easy-setup-for-ldquowork-item-only-viewrdquo-web-users-in-tfs-2010